# Is it correct and natural to say "just for educational purposes" when are asking for informaion?

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

Would you tell me if it is correct and natural to say just *for educational purposes* when you are asking for informaion that you need just to broaden your undestanding of things? For example:

> I understand that I don't have to know how that appliance works, but **just** **for educational purposes** can you explain it to me.

I've never heard anyone say it, but it's the only phrase I've been able to come up with to convey the message. Is it natural? Either way can you please give me alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's natural. No reason why you couldn't ask for information that way. However it is probably more common to ask

> Out of curiosity, will you please explain how the appliance works?

Note, it is more correct to ask "will you explain..." than "can you explain ...".
"Will" is requesting an explanation is actually given whilst "can" is only asking if it is possible to give the explanation.